# Confusion about difference between policy gradients of trajectories under stochastic/deterministic policies

Tags: random-variable, gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning

(If this isn't the right SE I'm sorry! Please point me in the correct direction)

I'm reading [this survey on policy search in robotics](https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/12051/4/2300000021-Deisenroth-Vol2-ROB-021_published.pdf), but I'm having a tough time with one part.

I'm going to assume the notation is self-explanatory here, but you can check the survey if things don't make sense. As the paper states, under a stochastic policy the probability of a trajectory $\tau$ is
$$
p_\theta(\tau) = \prod_t p(x_{t+1}|x_t, u_t) \pi_\theta(u_t|x_t, t)
$$
So compute the gradient of the log gives
$$
\nabla_\theta \log p_\theta(\tau) = \sum_t \nabla_\theta \log \pi_\theta(u_t|x_t, t)
$$
Here the terms $\log p(x_{t+1}|x_t, u_t)$ don't depend on $\theta$ so they drop out, meaning we don't have to worry about the system dynamics. Whereas for a deterministic policy we have
$$
p_\theta(\tau) = \prod_t p(x_{t+1}|x_t, \pi_\theta(x_t, t))
$$
Now we have a terms like 
$$
\nabla_\theta \log p_\theta(x_{t+1}|x_t, \pi_\theta(x_t, t)) =
\left. \frac{\partial \log p_\theta(x_{t+1}|x_t, u_t)}{\partial u_t}
\frac{\partial u_t}{\partial \theta} \right |_{u_t = \pi_\theta(x_t,t)}
$$
So we have to worry about the system dynamics.

This makes sense on the surface to me, but digging deeper I'm not really sure... Couldn't we imagine a "stochastic" policy which only has probability mass at one $u_t$ (and is therefore equivalently deterministic)? Also, as I've been relooking at it, I'm not sure why the system terms actually fall out in the stochastic case. Why is $\frac{\partial u_t}{\partial \theta} = 0$ here only? Changing $\theta$ certainly affects the draws of $u_t$. I'm assuming there's some issue with the difference between random/constant variables here that's throwing me off.